# Search queries report empty after moving site to HTTPS

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, https

I've noticed a few awkward bumps in analytics/search when moving my site from http to https, but almost all of them worked their way out...but the Aquisition > SEO > Queries report in Google Analyitics acts as if I got 0 impressions ever since SSL was added:

[image]

Search traffic is about average, corroborated by site hits (most traffic is search) and Webmaster Tools, so the chart isn't accurate, it's just *missing* in this view. My Google Analytics tracking code is working correctly and other reports in GA look just fine, so what's up with the search report?

Answer (score 2):

While making sure I wasn't doing anything stupid I found the problem on my own!

When you switch your site to HTTPS you're going to want to go into Property Settings, set the default URL to HTTPS at the top, and go to the "Adjust Search Console" button at the bottom.
[image]

Here you'll see a list of your Webmaster Tools sites (if you didn't already, add your HTTPS version of your site to Webmaster Tools), just pick the HTTPS one and that report now shows HTTPS search results *only*.

[image]

Unfortunately, like a few other analytics, you can't see your HTTP and HTTPS results in the same place, so you'll see dead stats before/after your HTTPS transition depending on which form you use in this particular report.